# What is the exact meaning of anachronism in coding(C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, coding-style, compiler-warnings

I am using visual studio 2017. In C++, I tried to assign a pointer to 'this' pointer. It showed compiler error as "assignment to 'this' (anachronism)". Anachronism means adding something into the period it can't exist like roman emperor checks computer. So is the compiler warning also like this. Or is there any specific meaning in coding for the word "anachronism"?.

Comment: It could have been allowed by some compilers before C++ was standardized in 1998?

Comment: But I'm more curious about *why* you want to assign to `this`? What problem is that supposed to solve? Perhaps you meant to assign to the object that `this` is pointing to, and you forgot to dereference `this`?

Answer (score 8):

A good while ago, `this` pointer could be assigned values. I met such assignments in the code of the Cfront compiler. I wrote about it in this note: [Celebrating the 30-th anniversary of the first C++ compiler: let's find the bugs in it](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0355/). Examples:

```
expr.expr(TOK ba, Pexpr a, Pexpr b)
{
  register Pexpr p;

  if (this) goto ret;
  ....
  this = p;
  ....
}

inline toknode.~toknode()
{
  next = free_toks;
  free_toks = this;
  this = 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason for doing this was that `operator new` hadn't been invented yet. Assigning to `this` allowed the constructor to allocate memory for the object. +1.

Answer (score 6):

Anachronism is something that was OK long time ago but not anymore.

Starting from **C++98**, `this` is an rvalue and as such cannot be assigned (i.e. cannot appear on the left from an assignment operator).
See **§9.3.2 The `this` pointer**:

> In the body of nonstatic (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a *non-lvalue* expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called.

Starting from C++11, `this` is [specified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.this#1) as a `prvalue`.

Answer (score 2):

From google:

*a thing belonging or appropriate to a period other than that in which it exists, especially a thing that is conspicuously old-fashioned.*

Which basically means that this used to be allowed in the past (probably by pre standards compliant compilers) but isn't allowed anymore.

Comment: I think anachronism isnt necessarily something that is not allowed or possible anymore. Eg using `new` and `delete` all over the place is an anachronism, poeple wrote code like that in the past but today it is just meeh

Answer (score 1):

This question tapped my curiosity, so I dug into my copies of all the ratified C++ standards and technical corrigenda I have  (which works out to everything between C++98 and C++17 inclusive).  None of them contain the word "anachronism" in any form.

The ARM (The C++ Annotated Reference Manual) by Ellis and Stroustrup, 1990  (a base document written to guide development of the C++ standard) has Section 18.3 entitled "Anachronisms".  The first paragraph of that section says

> The extensions provided here may be provided by an implementation to ease the use of C programs as C++ programs or to provide continuity from earlier C++ implementations.   Note that each of these features has undesirable aspects.  An implementation providing them should also provide a way for the user to ensure that they do not occur in a source file.  A C++ implementation is not obliged to provide these features.